# Drupal 8, не срабатывает JS при выводе по одному URL страницы и формы из модуля

Tags: drupal, drupal8, drupal7

Модуль создаёт форму, прикрепляет JS на определённом URL.

Если я создаю страницу с таким же URL, то выводится и страница и под ней моя форма из блока. Но JS уже не подгружается.

Как исправить подключение JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сначала пытался через контроллер добавить библиотеку с стилями и скриптами в свой плагин.
Не работало, если по такому же URL, что и плагин, создать страницу (материал) в админке.

Убрал контроллер, в модуле, в объявлении блока в build() прописал добавление библиотеки с стилями. Всё заработало